# How do I load two applet Jars to non-applet gui program?

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to find a way to correctly load both of the Jars (TestApplet.jar and Shared.jar) to a swing gui. I already succeeded to load TestApplet.jar but it gives NoClassDefFoundError exception because I haven't found out how to load Shared.jar too.

This is the HTML code on page:

```
<applet id="testapplet" class="topspacer" codebase="http://codebase.url.com/applets/" code="TestApplet" archive="TestApplet.jar,/Shared/Shared.jar" width="645" height="465">
<param name="initmessage" value="Initializing..." />
<!-- ... Other parameters ... -->
```

This is how I start the TestApplet:

```
ClassLoader clientClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("http://codebase.url.com/applets/TestApplet.jar")});
Applet loader = (Applet) clientClassLoader.loadClass("TestApplet").asSubclass(Applet.class).newInstance();
loader.init();
loader.start();
```

So basically, how do I correctly load the Shared.jar for TestApplet's use?
Just ask if you need more details or some clarification.

EDIT: And the error is this: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/shared/singleclient/SingleGame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding Shared.jar to the set of URLs in your `URLClassLoader`? Something like this:

```
ClassLoader clientClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{
    new URL("http://codebase.url.com/applets/TestApplet.jar"),
    new URL("http://codebase.url.com/applets/Shared.jar")
});
```

Alternatively, you could make sure that Shared.jar can be found by the parent `ClassLoader`, though including it in the `URLClassLoader` would more closely approximate the normal environment for applets.

Comment: Thanks, this works. So simple I didn't even think about it. :D

Comment: By the way, do you know how can I pass those parameters to the applet?

Comment: `<param name="initmessage" value="Initializing..." />` which is shown in the question for example.

Comment: @Henry: you can create your own implementation of `java.applet.AppletStub` and use that to pass in parameters.